# General term of a sequence with multiples of 6

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am struggling to fin the general term of the following sequence:

$$\begin{aligned}
\text{for} \ n = 1,..,5 & \rightarrow n\\
n=6 & \rightarrow n+1 \\
n=7 & \rightarrow n+3 \\
n=8 & \rightarrow n+5 \\
n=9 & \rightarrow n+7 \\
n=10 & \rightarrow n+9 \\
n=11 & \rightarrow n+11 \\
n=12 & \rightarrow n+13+1 \\
n=13 & \rightarrow n+15+3 \\
n=14 & \rightarrow n+17+5 \\
n=15 & \rightarrow n+19+7 \\
n=16 & \rightarrow n+21+9 \\
n=17 & \rightarrow n+23+11 \\
n=18 & \rightarrow n+25+13+1 \\
\vdots
\end{aligned}$$

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: $$x_n=\frac{1}{6} n (n+1)+\text{frac}\left(\frac{n}{6}\right) \left(5-6 \text{frac}\left(\frac{n}{6}\right)\right)$$ where frac is the fractional part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $I$ be the integer part of $\frac{n}{6}$. Then $$x_n=(2I+1)n+I-6I(I+1).$$

Comment: What is the idea behind $6I(I+1)$?

Comment: @cosmo5. For the later numbers one has to add on terms like $*-11,*-23, *- 35$ etc So I made these $I-12(1+2+...+I)$.